# Hibernate - Join using criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have two Entities:

- Customer

  - ID
- Car

  - CustomerID
  - LicenceNumber

All the examples I found using criteria and join were about going from the car to the customer, but I need to go the other way around:

I want to select customers that own a car with a given licence number. My problem is how to connect from the customer table to the car table since the foreign key is in the other table.

Comment: Give us what you have so far, so we can tell you how to edit your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a bidirectional relation to do that in Criteria.
Make sure you create a *ToMany relation to `Car` in `Customer`. Then you can simply select on `Customer` where `Car` list is not empty. Note that this does not change the database schema (unless you don't do the mapping correctly) and hibernate will use the fk on `Customer` in the `Car` table.